# Thunderbird deletes old messages without asking

Tags: email, imap

I'm using Thunderbird 102.13.0. I recently noticed, that mail downloaded (via IMAP) to my Inbox, disappear, when they are more than 6 months old, and I really mean "disappear": They are not in the "Deleted" folder either.

I checked the preferences whether there is a setting, which would purge automatic messages automatically, but I could not find any.

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: You (or your mail provider) may have a “sweep” rule that deletes or moves mail after a certain period.  Confirm with your mail admin first.

Comment: @Allan : Well, Thunderbird downloads the mail using IMAP, so it is stored locally. How could a sweep-rule from my ISP have impact on this? I don't know whether I have such a rule on my Mac. How can I verify this? I just had installed Thunderbird and, in the preferences, entered the account data of my mail account, as was provided by my ISP.

Comment: [IMAP is synced, not downloaded:(https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460924/119271) so if it’s deleted on the server, it’s deleted on the client.  Check with your mail hosting provider to see if they have any such rules.

Comment: Ah, this would explain it. The mail, which arrives on the server, can be accessed there with their web interface, and I download it to my client. However I do have configured this web interface to purge the mail after half a year, and I did not expect that this would affect my local copy. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Allan : BTW, my Thunderbird also has a so-called "Local Folder". From the link you posted in your comment, I would conclude that if I can persuade Thunderbird to copy the mail downloaded by IMAP, to the local folder, this should solve my problem. Do you happen to know whether it is possible to configure Thunderbird in this way?

Comment: Yup.  You can create local folders to store mail you want to keep.

Comment: @Allan: Sure, but how can I automatically copy incoming mail to the local folder? It's tedious to move it manually every time.

Comment: I haven’t used Thunderbird in a long while, (I use Outlook), but you might be able to create a rule (in TB)  that automatically copies the mail locally based on your criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s likely a rule (purge rule from comments) that is causing the issue.

IMAP synchronizes mail; it doesn’t download it.  Therefore, if you have a rule that “sweeps” out old email from the server after a certain amount if time it will also remove the mail from your client provided you haven’t copied it to a local folder.  See the following question and answer for additional details:

[Is content from webmail folders in Mail.app local?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/460922/119271)

Basically, if there’s something you want to keep, create a local folder that’s not synced with the server. Anything copied there will remain accessible there even if the mail provider deletes your account.  I do this with mails I wish to archive.

Comment: …and that's why I won't touch IMAP with a bargepole. I have locally-stored, fully backed-up POP3 going back 20 years to the first Mac I ever had at home. [I lost the previous decade by leaving my employer at that time, though had I been smarter back then could have kept that too]. When MS365 dropped POP support last year, I left MS & bought my own mailserver.

Comment: I couldn’t imagine managing that much mail.   I have my offline archived and all client related mails are attached to their records.  Receipts/orders are moved to Paperless and legal  stuff gets moved to their respective portfolios.

Comment: I have 16TB of storage on my main Mac & perhaps another 20 in the building, a bit of email is nothing in comparison to my 'real' work. It's all backed up on & off-site too. I just don't like losing stuff & I like being in charge of my own destiny, as far as humanly possible ;) I also hate having my phone full of mail. Once I've read it, which I only ever do if I'm away from my desk for the day/week, I want to clear it down completely. I basically don't want a mail history on my mobile devices at all. I guess I've been using POP3 30 years & it's worked well so far ;)